# Removing input formatting options and description from comment form

Tags: 7, theming, forms, comments, input-formats

How do I remove the input formatting options and descriptions from the comment form?

I'm not interested in a CSS and/or jquery based solution, nor am I interested in using the [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module, as I am using Drupal 7 and it specifically states it is not ready for production sites (besides the fact installing a module to do this seems like overkill).  I want the html sent over the wire to not have the "input format" related text at all.

Drupal drives me nuts sometimes, because some stuff that should be simple is ridiculously complex.

I've searched but no one seems to know how to do this. Here's some things I've found:

- [form_alter hide Text format option](http://drupal.org/node/1341034)
- [Hiding the comment form's input format selector: A zombifying experience](http://drupalzombie.com/article/hiding-comment-forms-input-format-selector-zombifying-experience)
- [Drupal 7 notes - Hiding unwanted form elements in comment forms](http://technonaturalist.net/blog/2011/02/drupal-7-notes-hiding-unwanted-form-elements-comment-forms)

Comment: Drupal is well Drupal..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok found this drupal issue discussing the matter: [Node and Comment Input Format fieldset is not working](http://drupal.org/node/1111308) (I found it by searching for "edit-comment-body-und-0-format" which html id of the fieldset that contains all the input format mumbo jumbo).

At the end of this issue is a link to the following site which gives a solution:
[How To Remove Format Options / Guideliness From Comments Textarea in Drupal 7](http://timonweb.com/how-remove-format-options-guideliness-comments-textarea-drupal-7).

Here's the code I'm using on my site, in template.php of my theme (I'm using a zen subtheme):

```
function mytheme_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

  $form['comment_body']['#after_build'][] = 'mytheme_customize_comment_form';

}

function mytheme_customize_comment_form(&$form) {
  $form[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
  return $form;
}
```

I just tried it and it does seem to be working. Woohoo!

Comment: very well. In the past I have used css on my site to hide the options

Comment: it should be noted that this (['format']['#access'] = FALSE) disables the Wysiwyg editor

Comment: @batibolix: for me it not just disables Wysiwyg editor, it also shows warning messages like "Undefined index: format in wysiwyg_pre_render_text_format" in wysiwyg module. Removing items from #pre_render array solves my problem

Answer (score 3):

Check this module https://drupal.org/project/simplify .

From the module's project page:

> Simplify allows particular fields to be hidden from the user interface. This helps to de-clutter forms and present a more user-friendly experience to content editors.

Very helpful to hide unnecessary tips and text format option under RTE